# Create user profile page laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes, laravel-routing

I was looking on the internet to do this, but I did not find nothing. I want to make this:

I have a table with users, I want to create a single page for every user with his information. That's not hard. But, what I'm trying to figure it out is the following. I want to get into this page with the following username localhost/user/username (username is the username of the user). The thing is how can I get the username from the URL and How can I do the routing for that? Provide me the documentation or something.

Thank you in advance.

PS: I am here right now

```
Route::get('pilot/info/{license}', function($license)
{
    return 'User '.$license;
});
```

My question here is how can I go to the controller sending the $license variable?
As going to the controller I am referring to doing that. But I also need to put the $license variable.

```
    Route::get('/pilot/login', array('uses' => 'PilotController@getLogin', 'as' => 'getLogin'));
```

Comment: Read [http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar Awesome that's exactly what I was looking for. I will work a bit on that and post my final code. Thanks!

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar Please check my problem now.

Comment: Try [simple CRUD](https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers) & create a [simple blog](https://medium.com/laravel-myanmar/tutorials-laravel-blog-f066f2e59588) & read documentation.

Comment: Is this right `Route::get('/pilot/info/{$id}', array('uses' => 'PilotController@info', 'as' => 'info'));`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've done here:

```
Route::get('pilot/info/{license}', function($license)
{
    return 'User '.$license;
});
```

Your controller will work in the same way.

```
Route::get('pilot/info/{license}', 'Controller@getLicense');
```

Will pass the `{license}` to the method as an argument. So all you need to do is add a `$license` parameter in your `getLicense` method and you can use it.